# Should I specify the SRV record "_jabber._tcp"?

Tags: xmpp, srv-record

I’m running an XMPP server and have specified the SRV records

- `_xmpp-client._tcp`, and
- `_xmpp-server._tcp`.

I often see that people also specify `_jabber._tcp` (for example, in [Alnitak’s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/150175/131794)), but I can’t find this value in [RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120).

What is `_jabber._tcp` for? Should I specify it, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The _jabber SRV resource record is deprecated. Don't worry about it unless you want to support old, legacy clients.

http://mailman.jabber.org/pipermail/jadmin/2007-January/098908.html

SRV records are described in RFC 2782. They are DNS records that applications can use to locate services on the network.